# Finding the direct object

Tags: direct-objects

In the following sentence, I'm trying to figure out which is the **direct object**:

> On a trip like this, one must be careful about gas consumption.

I know that the subject is *one* and the verb is *be* but I'm not sure what the direct object would be.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's not surprising, since this sentence is intransitive and therefore doesn't have a direct object.

Answer (score -1):

Intransitive verbs don’t need an object so in your sentence there isn’t any object